# How to design a complex UI without interface builder? (iphone)

Tags: iphone, user-interface, interface-builder

I've seen many people saying it's easier to code your UI directly than to manipulate them in IB.

I know how to create UI objects from code but it just seems unnecessarily complicated, especially when you have 10+ subviews/controllers in one view(screen).

**1. How do you visualize the UI layout when you create UI from code?**

**2. How do you make sure you are following the apple guidelines when placing the UI objects? (IB shows the blue dashed line to suggest you the correct(i guess) positions)**

**3. How do you manage to separate the UI creation part and the UI placement part in code? (maybe to figure out the UI layout easily)**

and so on..

I wish there was a tutorial or example that can answer the above questions but hard to google.

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: I guess it's easier to use IB as a beginner, and to code it as you gain experience.

Comment: umm. one thing i lack in ib is .. not able to pass argument to init method of objects. I'd like to start on coding UI. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am creating my UIs from code with config files.
I have a test iPhone app that reads a config file and displays the UI, so i can tweak it.

Comment: umm... i'll have to think about that, little more detail will be helpful though?

Comment: What kind of details you need?

Comment: maybe a sample snippet of the config file or a little list of what it contains?